# Upload Wordpress Media Api From Local File

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl, upload

I'm trying to upload my local image to my blog on wordpress.com, I try this code

```
$request = curl_init('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/mywordpressbloganonym.wordpress.com/media/new');

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'media' => '@C:/Users/aditia/myimage.jpg',
      'media[0]' => '@C:/Users/aditia/myimage.jpg',
      'media[]' => '@C:/Users/aditia/myimage.jpg'
    ));

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
    "Authorization: BEARER mybrearertokenrfromauth"
  ));

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
echo curl_exec($request);

// close the session
curl_close($request);
```

I always get

```
{"media":[],"errors":[{"error":"upload_error","message":"File is empty. Please upload something more substantial."},{"error":"upload_error","message":"File is empty. Please upload something more substantial."}]}
```

i'm using https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1.1/post/sites/$site/media/new/ 
but using curl directly from console is working, please help is there something missing in my code?

Comment: Is your file **not** empty as the error message clearly states?

Comment: hi, I already solve this problem '@' on php 5.5 is deprecated, use The CURLFile class instead, http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php